# Infinite scroll with existing method in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i want to implement infinit scroll in the code below (ngOnInit). The npm package ngx-infinite-scroll helps me to call the onScroll() event. When i scroll down the onScroll will be fired.

I dont know rxjs very well -its new to me.

In the switchMap i call the service method that needs the page number. Now, every call send only one page. Its hard coded. My question is can i append another pages (to the **this.testSearchResult$** ) and when yes how? And how can i manage the new search when the term changed.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.testSearchResult$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 500ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(500),
      filter(() => this.term1.length > 0 && this.term2.length > 0 && this.term3.length > 0),
      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap(() =>
        this.testSearchService.searchTest(this.term1, this.term2, this.term3, ITEMS_PER_PAGE, this.page)
      )
    );

    this.testSearchResult$.subscribe(res => {
      this.currentTestPage = res;
      this.clearCheckList();
    });

}
```

```
  onScroll() {
   // this.page++ when the scrollbar is at 80%

  }
```

best regards

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question when you say "Its possible to add the n-th page to the existing observable? How is it possible to reset the Obsevabl when a term is changed."

Comment: Hey, its now clear?

Answer (score 0):

Something like following:

```html
import { combineLatest, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, filter, map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

page = 0

currentPage$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.testSearchResult$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 500ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(500),
      filter(
        () =>
          this.term1.length > 0 &&
          this.term2.length > 0 &&
          this.term3.length > 0
      ),
      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      map(() => {
   this.page = 1
        this.currentPage$.next(this.page)
        return { term1: this.term1, term2: this.term2, term3: this.term3 };
      })
    );

    combineLatest(this.testSearchResult$, this.currentPage$.asObservable())
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([{ term1, term2, term3 }, page]) =>
          this.testSearchService.searchTest(
            term1,
            term2,
            term3,
            ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
            page
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.currentTestPage.push(...res);
        this.clearCheckList();
      });

}

currentPage$ = new Subject()

onScroll() {
   this.page++
   this.currentPage$.next(this.page)

  }
```

PS: It does require a little modification to avoid repeat API call when resetting page no to `1` for new term search. It was just quickest answer I could write here